# Combining F77 and F95 fortran code

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm working on some scientific code that is mostly F77 but also some F95. In places, I need to include F77 code into my F95 code. Is there a way to get this code to play nicely within my code by using a particular compiler flag or something? I'm using gfortran and occasionally ifort. It is possible for me to modify the legacy code but I would need to do it in a sensible way to maintain backwards compatibility with other F77 code while also being forwards compatible with F95 code.

I get errors like:

```
cstruc:16.12:
    Included at mod_op.f90:6:

      REAL*8
            1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
cstruc:17.6:
    Included at mod_op.f90:6:

     &       RH, RH1,      ! ln rho
      1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
cstruc:18.6:
    Included at mod_op.f90:6:

     &       RHP, RHP1,    ! d ln rho / d ln p
      1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
cstruc:19.6:
    Included at mod_op.f90:6:

     &       RHT, RHT1,    ! d ln rho / d ln T
      1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

cstruc looks like this:

```
  REAL*8
 &       RH, RH1,      ! ln rho
 &       RHP, RHP1,    ! d ln rho / d ln p
 &       RHT, RHT1,    ! d ln rho / d ln T
 &       PSI,          ! ln Lambda (for degenerate gas)
 &       RHPSI,        ! d ln rho / d PSI
 &       RHPSIP,       ! d2 ln rho / d PSI d ln P
 &       RHPSIT,       ! d2 ln rho / d PSI d ln T
 &       PL,           ! P at J1
 &       TONI          ! T at J1
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem shouldn't be F77 vs F95, but free format vs. fixed format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some exceptions, Fortran 77 code is Fortran 95 code.  I guess that your errors come from that you are attempting to `include` fixed-form source code (your F77 code in cstruc) into a free-form source code file mod_op.f90.  This is unlikely to end well.

Most compilers will assume a file ending in ".f90" is free-form, so if you really are using fixed-form then you will need a compiler flag to override the assumption.

It is possible to combine free- and fixed-form code into a final object (each compiled separately), but a good suggestion as to how to resolve the problems you are seeing can come only with more detail.

However, if you are attempting with your `include` to create a module to replace a common block, then there is no reason why you can't use the F95 feature with fixed-form.  Just do that selectively.

Alternatively, you can see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22049200/3157076) by Vladimir F which explains how to write source code that is valid as both free-form and fixed-form source.  You can use this to modify the Fortran 77 fixed-form code to be `include`-able by the Fortran 90 free-form code while still being compilable as fixed-form (but not valid Fortran 77).

Comment: Ooh, interesting.. So if I just write the code in fixed form but compile as Fortran 90/95, it should be alright..I tried to convert my code completely to F77 but then I realised that I needed the modern features. I'll give that a try tomorrow :) Thanks!

Comment: is there any easy way to convert from F90 free form to F90 fixed form?

Comment: @amrods without using an automated tool (and I don't know of one), I'd say: not easy at all.  Also, I'd probably say that any effort spent doing that is much better put towards solving other problems.  Free-form source is generally _much_ more readable and less prone to errors.  It's also much easier to modify fixed-form to (idiosyncratic) free-form, and "modernization" tools do exist there.

Comment: F90 standardized Fortran again after 12 years of discussion, but it was based on the existing Fortan compilers -- many if not most of which already supported free-format input.  "F77" is now used to indicate standard compliance, but every F77 compiler I ever used also had non-standard extensions -- including free-format.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to try the "intersection" form from http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Continuation+lines

It is legal as both free and fixed source form.

Comment: I came across this but it didn't quite work for some reason. I'll try it again though. Thanks!