# Fortran write statement raising syntax error, removing write statement raises other errors all over the code, even before the removed line

Tags: fortran, syntax-error, stdout, subroutine

The problematic line:

```
   if (nbuff(i).ne.nbuff(j)) write (6,*) 'swap mode:',i,' ',buff(i),' to ',buff(j)
```

which raises the error:

```
#5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...
```

I expect that this line is just a write to stdout, so it shouldn't cause any issues to remove it. Here is the surronding section:

```
c     **** update symmetry info ****

      buff94= symm94
      buff= symm
      nbuff= nsymm

      do i= 1,n3
    fir(i)= 0.d0
        nsymm(i)= 0
    do j= 1,n3
      if (abs(rot(i,j)).gt.0.01) then
        if (nsymm(i).eq.0) then
      
          
          nsymm(i)= nbuff(j)
          symm(i)= buff(j)
          symm94(i)= buff94(j)
        else if (nsymm(i).ne.nbuff(j)) then
          write (6,*) 'ERROR: mixed symmetry',i,' ',symm(i),' ',buff(j)
          stop 'MIXED SYMM on freq rescalling'
        end if
      end if
    end do
      end do

      if (.not.rescale) then
        do i= nrt+1,n3
      if (abs(1.d0-abs(rot(i,i))).gt.1.d-5) write (6,*) 'rot error',i,i,rot(i,i)
      do j= nrt+1,i-1
        if (abs(rot(i,j)).gt.1.d-5) write (6,*) 'rot error',i,j,rot(i,j)
      end do
    end do
        write (6,*) 'reeval norm modes checked'
      end if
```

Removing it, though, raises errors all over the code, even in lines *before* the removed line. It isn't clear why. Here is a quick overview of those errors:
[image: a list of vscode errors]

Could someone let me know where the error actually is? I've done a lot of googling and I can't tell what the issue actually is.

Thanks!

For anyone whom it might help, here is the full file. It defines a subroutine that will be called from the main file. Apologies, I know it's difficult to read. This is legacy code dating back over 20 years, so I'm doing my best to fix it.

```
      subroutine fcintco (n3,nv,ni,m3,mr, b,br,c,eval,redtr,zptl,ratmas,iztype, fcscale,calcint,
     $  fcint,cint,rot,w,wk,g, symm94,symm,nsymm,fir)

c     **** scales, and recalcs normal modes ****
c     **** if calcint=.true., determins energy defivs wrt internal vars ****
c
c     **** fcscale on input is fc scaling factors s b t (prop then improp) ****
c     **** fcint on output is force cons in red int coords
c     **** cint is norm modes in red int coords
c     **** rot is transformation form old norm coords to new if rescaling used 
c     **** w is trans from int coords to normal modes
c     **** wk, g are work arrays

      implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
c      real*8 c(m3,m3),redtr(mr,mr),zptl(m3),eval(m3),ratmas(m3),cint(mr,mr),w(m3,mr),
c     $   fcint(mr,mr),wk(mr,mr),g(mr,mr),b(m3,m3),br(mr,m3),rot(m3,m3),fir(m3),fcscale(4)
      integer iztype(mr),nsymm(m3),nbuff(m3)
      logical rescale,calcint
      character*3 symm94(m3),symm(m3),buff94(m3),buff(m3)

      common /cons/ au2ang,au2cm,amu2au

      rescale= fcscale(1).ne.1.d0 .or. fcscale(2).ne.1.d0
      rescale= rescale .or. fcscale(3).ne.1.d0
      write (6,*) 'FCINTCO: int force con freq rescale flag=',rescale
      write (6,*) 'calcint=',calcint
      if (.not.rescale .and. .not.calcint) return

c     **** calc neg eigenvales after zero ones ****
      nrt= 0
      nneg= 0
      do i= 1,n3
    if (abs(eval(i)).lt.2.d0) then
      nrt= nrt + 1
    else if (eval(i).lt.0.d0) then
      nneg= nneg + 1
    end if
      end do
      write (6,*) 'nrt=',nrt,' nneg=',nneg

      do i= 1,nv
    do j= 1,n3
      xxx= 0.D0
      do k= 1,n3
         xxx= xxx + b(i,k)*c(k,j)
      end do
      wk(i,j)= xxx
    end do
      end do

c     **** trans from Z vars to norm mode displacements ****

      do i= 1,n3
        do j= 1,ni
      xx= 0.d0
      do k= 1,nv
        xx= xx + wk(k,i) * redtr(j,k)
      end do
      w(i,j)= xx
    end do
      end do

c     **** wk = sqrt of G matrix in red int coords ****

      do i= 1,ni
    do j= 1,i
      g(i,j)= 0.D0
      do k= 1,n3
        g(i,j)= g(i,j) + br(i,k) * br(j,k) / ratmas(k)**2
      end do
      g(j,i)= g(i,j)
    end do
      end do

      call mpower (wk,g,mr,ni,0.5D0,fcint(1,1),fcint(1,2))
      write (6,*) 'FCINTCO; eigvals of G='
      write (6,'(10f10.7)') (fcint(i,1),i=1,ni)

c   **** Force cons in red int coords ****

      do i= 1,ni
    do j= 1,ni
       ee= 0.d0
       do k= 1,n3
         ee0= (eval(k)/au2cm)**2
         if (eval(k).lt.0.d0) ee0= - ee0
         ee= ee + w(k,i) * w(k,j) * ee0
       end do
       fcint(i,j)= ee * fcscale(abs(iztype(i))) * fcscale(abs(iztype(j)))
    end do
      end do

c     **** G**1/2 . F . G**1/2 ****

      call mmult   (mr,ni,g,fcint,wk)
      call mmulttr (mr,ni,cint,wk,g)
C      write (6,*) 'FG matrix'
C      write (6,'(5f12.4)') ((cint(i,j),j=1,5),i=1,5)

c     **** normal modes in red int basis ****

      call tred2e (mr,ni,cint,wk,g,cint)
      call tql2e  (mr,ni,     wk,g,cint,ier)
C      write (6,*) 'Eigvals of FG:'
C      write (6,'(10g12.3)') (wk(i,1),i=1,ni)

      eval= 0.d0
      ii= 0
      do i= 1,ni
        wk(i,1)= sign (sqrt(abs(wk(i,1))),wk(i,1)) * au2cm 
    if (wk(i,1).lt.-2.d0) then
      ii= ii + 1
          write (6,'(i4,2f8.1)') i,eval(i),wk(i,1)
      eval(i)= wk(i,1)
    else if (wk(i,1).gt.2.d0) then
      ii= ii + 1
          write (6,'(i4,2f8.1)') i,eval(i),wk(i,1)
      eval(ii+nrt)= wk(i,1)
    end if
      end do

c     **** copy over original trans/rot modes ****

      do i= nneg+1,nneg+nrt
        do j= 1,n3
      g(j,i)= c(j,i)
    end do
      end do

c     ************ revised normal modes in Cartes coords if freq rescaling used ************

C      if (.not.rescale) then
C   do i= 1,n3
C     do j= 1,n3
C       rot(i,j)= 0.d0
C     end do
C     rot(i,i)= 1.d0
C   end do
CC  return
C      end if

c     **** express FC matrix in cartes coords as F = BR(T) . F(int) . BR ****

      do i= 1,n3
        do j= 1,ni
      wk(i,j)= 0.d0
      do k= 1,ni
        wk(i,j)= wk(i,j) + br(k,i) * fcint(k,j)
      end do
    end do
      end do

      do i= 1,n3
        do j= 1,n3
      g(i,j)= 0.d0
      do k= 1,ni
        g(i,j)= g(i,j) + wk(i,k) * br(k,j)
      end do
      g(i,j)= g(i,j) / ratmas(i) / ratmas(j)
    end do
      end do

      call tred2e (mr,n3,g,wk,wk(1,2),g)
      call tql2e  (mr,n3,  wk,wk(1,2),g,ier)
      do i= 1,n3
        wk(i,1)= sign (sqrt(abs(wk(i,1))),wk(i,1)) * au2cm
C        write (6,'(i5,2f10.1)') i,eval(i),wk(i,1)
      end do

      if (.not.rescale) then
        do i= 1,n3
          if (abs(eval(i)-wk(i,1)).gt.2.) then
            write (6,'(i5,2f10.1)') i,eval(i),wk(i,1)
        stop 'rescaled freqs not same as freqs from red ints'
          end if
        end do
        write (6,*) 'reeval freqs in Cartes coords checked'
      end if

c     **** copy over orig rot/trans modes ****

      do i= nneg+1,nneg+nrt
        do j= 1,n3
      g(j,i)= c(j,i)
    end do
      end do

c     **** rotn matrix from orig cartes ncs to final ****

      do i= 1,n3
        do j= 1,n3
      rot(i,j)= 0.d0
      do k= 1,n3
        rot(i,j)= rot(i,j) + g(k,i) * c(k,j)
      end do
    end do
      end do

c     **** replace the orig normal modes, freq, and zptl ****

      write (6,*) 'updating norm modes, freqs, and zptl after rescaling'
      do i= 1,n3
        eval(i)= wk(i,1)
    if (abs(eval(i)).gt.1.)
     $          zptl(i)= sqrt (au2cm/abs(eval(i))) * au2ang

        do j= 1,n3
      c(i,j)= g(i,j)
    end do
      end do

c     **** update symmetry info ****

      buff94= symm94
      buff= symm
      nbuff= nsymm

      do i= 1,n3
    fir(i)= 0.d0
        nsymm(i)= 0
    do j= 1,n3
      if (abs(rot(i,j)).gt.0.01) then
        if (nsymm(i).eq.0) then
      
          
          nsymm(i)= nbuff(j)
          symm(i)= buff(j)
          symm94(i)= buff94(j)
        else if (nsymm(i).ne.nbuff(j)) then
          write (6,*) 'ERROR: mixed symmetry',i,' ',symm(i),' ',buff(j)
          stop 'MIXED SYMM on freq rescalling'
        end if
      end if
    end do
      end do

      if (.not.rescale) then
        do i= nrt+1,n3
      if (abs(1.d0-abs(rot(i,i))).gt.1.d-5) write (6,*) 'rot error',i,i,rot(i,i)
      do j= nrt+1,i-1
        if (abs(rot(i,j)).gt.1.d-5) write (6,*) 'rot error',i,j,rot(i,j)
      end do
    end do
        write (6,*) 'reeval norm modes checked'
      end if

c     **** revised transform normal modes to orthog internal coords in wk ****

      do i= 1,nv
    do j= 1,n3
      xxx= 0.D0
      do k= 1,n3
         xxx= xxx + b(i,k)*c(k,j)
      end do
      wk(i,j)= xxx
    end do
      end do

c     **** trans from Z vars to norm mode displacements ****

      do i= 1,n3
        do j= 1,ni
      xx= 0.d0
      do k= 1,nv
        xx= xx + wk(k,i) * redtr(j,k)
      end do
      w(i,j)= xx
    end do
      end do

c     **** copy vectors in cint down to standard location with nneg and nrt ****

C      write (0,*) 'ni,nv=',ni,nv
      ii= ni-nv+nneg
      do i= nrt+nneg+1,nrt+nv
    ii= ii + 1
C   write (0,*) 'copy vec:',i,ii
    do j= 1,ni
      cint(j,i)= cint(j,ii)
    end do
      end do

      end
```

Comment: How long is that problematic line (presumably longer than 72 columns)? Why is the line declaring `g`, for example, as an array commented out, when the subroutine wants `g` to be an array?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75153392/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @francescalus seems to be too modest to point OP at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119286/error-expected-a-right-parenthesis-in-expression-at-1 which may well be the immediate source of one of the problems reported.

Comment: And on closer inspection it's remarkable that the code in the first block shown to us does not contain *the problematic line*.  What are we supposed to be looking at?

Comment: The subroutine listing in the last code block does not appear to contain that line either. Why are we shown that subroutine?

Comment: The way the code is written is really ugly with implicit typing and very inconsistent indentation. I understand it is legacy code but when preparing a [mcve] please care about these points and use `impicit none` and indent the small reproducing example consistently.